# ListBox does not get updated, even if it's set to ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I use Prism. Data provider works correctly (SQLite here).

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CategoryList}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>

public class ListsViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private readonly IDataProvider _dataProvider;
    private readonly IRegionManager _regionManager;
    public DelegateCommand ClickAddCategory { get; set; }

    private string categoryName;
    public string CategoryName
    {
        get { return categoryName; }
        set { SetProperty(ref categoryName, value); }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<ExtraCategory> categoryList;
    public ObservableCollection<ExtraCategory> CategoryList
    {
        get 
        { 
            if (categoryList == null) return _dataProvider.GetCategoryList();
            else return categoryList; 
        }
        set { SetProperty(ref categoryList, value); }
    }

    public ListsViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager,  IDataProvider dataProvider)
    {
        _dataProvider = dataProvider;
        _regionManager = regionManager;
        ClickAddCategory = new DelegateCommand(ClickedAddCategory);
        //MessageBox.Show("Hello from " + this.ToString());
    }

    private void ClickedAddCategory()
    {
        ExtraCategory newCategoryFromForm = new ExtraCategory(CategoryName);
        CategoryList.Add(newCategoryFromForm);
        _dataProvider.AddCategory(newCategoryFromForm);
    }
}
```

If I change the line:

```
CategoryList.Add(newCategoryFromForm);
```

to

```
CategoryList = _dataProvider.GetCategoryList();
```

everything would work fine because code inside set {} will run but that's not a solution. I would really appreciate some help. Also I really don't want to break MVVM pattern.

Comment: just a test, first set CategoryList = null then set the CategoryList = _dataProvider.GetCategoryList();

Comment: Or you can do CategoryList.Clear(); CategoryList.AddRange(_dataProvider.GetCategoryList());

Comment: I am building app using WPF and Prism library and do the second option and it work fine for me.

Comment: @MuhammadWaqasAziz Thanks for the answer but I really want to know why ObservableCollection doesn't update the ListBox even if it implements INotifyOnCollectionChange interface. I would like to also reduce usage of _dataProvider to minimum. Maybe creating derived class from ObservableCollection and implementing ICloneable interface to it and then assigning clone of categoryList to categoryList would be solution.

Comment: INotifyCollectionChange looks for changes in the collection not for reference changes, this might be helpful https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1004644/ObservableCollection-Simply-Explained, and WPF binds to defaultView not the actual list https://stackoverflow.com/a/7636980/5639143

Comment: once the reference of the original observable collection  is changed, then its connection to UI is lost, and it will not reflect any changes event if you add or remove item from it the only solution here is, CategoryList.Clear(); CategoryList.AddRange(_dataProvider.GetCategoryList()); Thats IT.

Comment: @MuhammadWaqasAziz Thanks for help but I find Haukinger's solution the one I was looking for. There's no need for creating private field for ObservableCollection and you don't have to manually refresh listBox - just CategoryList.Add(newCategoryFromForm). I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to put an `ObservableCollection` in a property without setter. And you want the value to stay the same.

```
private ObservableCollection<ExtraCategory> categoryList;
public ObservableCollection<ExtraCategory> CategoryList
{
    get 
    { 
        if (categoryList == null) return _dataProvider.GetCategoryList();
        else return categoryList; 
    }
    set { SetProperty(ref categoryList, value); }
}
```

This gives you a new `ObservableCollection` everytime you call `CategoryList.get`, i.e. `CategoryList.Add(newCategoryFromForm);` fetches a new list, adds the new item, then discards the list (returning a value from a property's getter does not magically set a backing field).

I'd do it this way:

```
public ObservableCollection<ExtraCategory> CategoryList { get; }
```

and in constructor:

```
CategoryList = _dataProvider.GetCategoryList();
```

Comment: That's the way it works and I want use it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

use and install nuget package [PropertyChange.Fody](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged).

Your class would look like this:

```
public class ListsViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
     public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

     private readonly IDataProvider _dataProvider;

     private readonly IRegionManager _regionManager;

     public DelegateCommand ClickAddCategory { get; set; }

     public string CategoryName { get; set; }

     public ObservableCollection<ExtraCategory> CategoryList { get; set; }

     public ListsViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager,  IDataProvider dataProvider)
     {
         _dataProvider = dataProvider;
         _regionManager = regionManager;
         ClickAddCategory = new DelegateCommand(ClickedAddCategory);
         CategoryList = _dataProvider.GetCategoryList();
         //MessageBox.Show("Hello from " + this.ToString());
     }

     private void ClickedAddCategory()
     {
          ExtraCategory newCategoryFromForm = new ExtraCategory(CategoryName);
          CategoryList.Add(newCategoryFromForm);
         _dataProvider.AddCategory(newCategoryFromForm);
     }
}
```

I'm sure it will work perfectly

If what you want is to update the list use a method and bind a command to execute when you want to refresh

Comment: Just out of curiosity: what's Fody's job in this? There's not even a changing property here. Also, why do you make `ClickAddCategory` and `CategoryList` writeable?

Comment: Precisely, fody is in charge of doing that work for you, on the changing properties. Work more comfortably and you don't have to do all that to notify the properties

Comment: Yes, this helps if you have trivial properties that only notify when changing and do nothing else. My point is - we don't have even those in this example, everything's read-only except for the _content_ of the `CategoryList`.

Comment: I put it like this because it was previously in your class, the point was that you see the benefits of propertychange.fody

Comment: You don't have to use a private field to notify